# Create newsletter template in Lotus Notes 8.5

Tags: lotus-notes

How can I create a template to circulate company newsletter via lotus notes 8.5 in the body of the email, so not as an attachment? I'm thinking blog style with a few images, header texts etc... I can merely cut and paste the text into it and hit send. Is this possible please?

Comment: I found this doing a google search: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.notes85.help.doc%2Fapp_notes_templates_r.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply trying to distribute a formatted email, or would you prefer to use a blog where people can reply and give feedback publicly?

Formatted email in Notes is relatively easy, and yes, you could just type the content in something else and then paste it into the content of the email.

Alternatively, create a blog: File - Application - New, Choose a server, give it a title and then choose the 'Domino Blog' template.  Ask your Admin if you need assistance on the correct server. My blog uses Notes: http://www.matnewman.com

Once you have a blog up and running you could send an email with a link to the entry to those you want to read the content, and by doing that you're not sending around a huge email message which may chew up people's quotas. With a blog you also have the advantage of not having "Reply-To-All" comment and thread issues in email.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that a Template in Notes is something else than I expect you are looking for. A Notes template holds the design of a complete Notes application. This is what is described by the documentation addresed by the link in your question.

I guess you are looking for a template to the contents of a single email. You should check out Stationary in your Notes mail. This may be what you are looking for.